# annotation_logticks() and coord_flip() seem incompatible

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get an error that seems to be combined by using `annotation_logticks()` and `coord_flip()` on the same plot. For instance:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  annotation_logticks(sides="l") +
  coord_flip()
```

gives the error `Error in unit(yticks$y, "native") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`. `traceback()` gives results that I don't totally understand, but which seem to have something to do with assigning units.

On the other hand, `annotation_logticks()` or `coord_flip()` *alone* doesn't cause any problem.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  annotation_logticks(sides="l") #+
  #coord_flip()
```

works fine, as does

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  #annotation_logticks(sides="l") #+
  coord_flip()
```

I could switch the `x` and `y` mappings to avoid `coord_flip()`, but this is not ideal (I have to rewrite old plots if I want to add `annotation_logticks()` for instance).

Comment: It is a bug. You should contact the maintainer.

Comment: Issue filed at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/881

Comment: issue fixed. I sent a pull request. You can use my github version as workaround.

Comment: 5 years later, it's still broken as of ggplot2 3.1.0 (or development version 3.1.0.9000). Same error. Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed in ggplot2 version 3.3.4 by [this PR](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4431).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  annotation_logticks(sides="l") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>